# Training a RandomForest is slow on a computing cluster

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have an account to a computing cluster than runs on Linux. I'm using scikit-learn to train a Random Forest classifier with 1000 trees on a very large dataset. I tried to use *all* the cores of the computing cluster by running the following code:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(data, Y)
```

However when I run the code I see that only 1.2% of the CPUs are being used! So why it's not using all the cores that exists? And how to solve this please?

Edit: I saw that my problem could be relevant to the one in this link, but I wasn't able to understand the solution. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1053

Comment: Because the people running the cluster aren't going to be foolish enough to let you have ALL the cores ALL the time! On clusters we have to learn to share. I don't know how many cores they've allotted you, but 1.2% of the CPU could be very generous. Usually clusters have a submission system where you can request more cores for your job.

Comment: @AndyG yes that's true, I'm allowed to get as much cores as I want and I allocated 10 CPUs from 40. But the CPU usage is very low! 1.2%!!

Comment: Python has a global Global Interpreter Lock, are you running on jython?

Comment: @Victory I'm just running with 'python script.py'. It's just the normal python 2.7

Comment: I don't know `RandomForestClassifier` exactly but if feels like you want to do some parallel computing in python. Out of the box python isn't really suited for this. jython lives on top of java which knows how to properly utilize more than one core.

Comment: Have you tried to set `n_jobs` to `10`? How many cores are on a chip? Are they physical chips or is there hyperthreading? Are you granted exclusive access when a job is running or are there other jobs?

Comment: @AndyG I just submitted a job with n_job set to 10 to see if this works. Some hosts has hyberthreading and others not. I have a shared access, but one can select how much CPUs he needs from a host.

Comment: @AndyG please see the 'edit' in my question, there might be a problem in scikit itself.

Comment: this might not be the root of your problem but Sklearn will run in parallel in all cores of a single machine. It will NOT run on cores from different machines in your cluster, this would imply knowing about the architecture of your cluster and communicating via the network. For this you will have to use a solution like python parallel.

Comment: @Victory scikit-learn has parallel processing support built-in. In the latest release, its Random Forest code can run almost entirely without the GIL.

Comment: @AlexTwain The solution alluded to in the issue has been merged into the latest scikit-learn. If you upgrade, you will get a *much* faster, *much* more parallel random forest learner (says one of the people who optimized it).

Comment: @larsmans I have scikit-learn 0.14.1

Comment: @AlexTwain Then you need to upgrade to current master in order to get really good performance.

Comment: @larsmans I can't find what is the current most up-to-date version. Is there a more recent version than mine?

Comment: You have the latest release. If you want faster RFs, you need to install the unstable version with `pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git`. Of course, you may encounter bugs in such a version.

Comment: @larsmans if I install this then it will replace my current scikit version, rigth? How can I revert back to the stable version if I found bugs? Also with the unstable version all I have to do is putting n_jobs=-1 right?

Comment: @AlexTwain Yes and yes. But you can install it into a `virtualenv` for testing.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the root of your problem (as `n_jobs=-1` should automatically detect and use all cores in your master node) but Sklearn will run in parallel in all cores of a single machine in your cluster. By default it will NOT run on cores from different machines in your cluster as this would imply knowing about the architecture of your cluster and communicating via the network which sklearn doesn't know how to do, as it varies from cluster to cluster.

For this you will have to use a solution like ipython parallel. See the [excellent tutorial](https://github.com/ogrisel/parallel_ml_tutorial) by Oliver Grisel if you want to use the full power of your cluster.

I recommend that you update sklearn to the latest version, try your code locally(ideally under the same OS, sklearn version), debug the scaling behavior and CPU utilization by setting `n_jobs=1,2,3...` and benchmarking the fit. For example if `n_jobs=1` doesn't have a high utilization rate in one core in the cluster but it does in your local PC, this would indicate a problem with the cluster and not with the code. Sometimes the top command in a cluster behaves differently, you should consult this with the admin.